# TensorFlow Android Detector Demo - Why Crop?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I was looking across the code in tensorflow android demo in DetectorActivity [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java)

Was wondering why there is a need to crop the camera preview image to a 300 x 300 dimension before feeding it into the classifier?

Using different dimension seem to affect the result from the classifier. Is this crop dimension influenced by the .pb (or images used to train the model)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all to train a model on your own with python, you need a config file and a checkpoint (so you don't start training from the start). The config files determine if you're reaching for speed (for realtime cases) or accuracy. There is a list of them provided by google you can find it under this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs). If you check the [ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config) you will notice that the images will be resized before the training process and that will result in high speed real time recognition but it will affect the accuracy.

Now to answer your question if you trained your model with a similar config file than applying the crop you mentioned will help getting the optimal accuracy with the optimal speed.

If you're using the frozen.pb provided by the demo **ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export.pb** it's trained with the same config file I mentioned before, so it make sense to feed the detector an image with the same dimensions as the data he was trained for.

So the overall purpose to this cropping is to optimize the speed since we're detecting objects in realtime.

I hope that helps clarify somethings.